# Date field in SharePoint Add-In displays the day before in debugger? Strange issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have two date fields. Start and End Date . If i choose 10/25/2017 , when i debug it shows the value 24/10/2017 .

After some debugging , when item is being saved i can see the correct values. Once the item is saved , and then i read it with caml query , i get a day before. My opinion , because the server is hosted on azure , maybe when the item is saved it takes consideration of the location ? But i have also changed the regional settings to the correct ones.

Has anyone noticed this ever before ?

This happens with any date I choose

This is the code i use , after i added the list item :

```
using (clientContext)
        {
            if (clientContext != null)
            {
                List leaveRequest = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("LeaveRequest");

                CamlQuery getApprovedLeaves = new CamlQuery();

                string statusApproved = "Approved";

                getApprovedLeaves.ViewXml =
                    @"<View>
                            <Query>
                                <Where>

                                    <Eq>
                                        <FieldRef Name='Status'/>
                                        <Value Type = 'Choice'>" + statusApproved + @"</Value>
                                    </Eq>

                                </Where>
                           </Query>
                           </View>";

                ListItemCollection approvedLeaves = leaveRequest.GetItems(getApprovedLeaves);

                clientContext.Load(approvedLeaves);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

 //Here is where the condition takes place. The "StartDate" and "EndDate" fields take a date of 1 days less. Its kind is UTC
 if (currentDate.Date >= Convert.ToDateTime(approvedLeaveItem["StartDate"]).Date && currentDate.Date <= Convert.ToDateTime(approvedLeaveItem["EndDate"]).Date)
                        {
                            conflictInfo[0] = "YES";
                            conflictInfo[1] = Convert.ToString(approvedLeaveItem["Requester"]);
                            break;
                        }
```

It correctly returns 1 item which is approved but instead of StartDate = 25/10/2017 it shows 24 October.

**Please note** that when i add the date it displays it in format 10/25/2017 but in **debug** it shows 24 October

Comment: Is this issue happen only in the Debug Mode? could you please post a piece of your code? also, try to check the *Regional Settings* in your site setting!

Comment: @M.Qassas I ve include more information for my issue as requested

Comment: Also i changed the regional settings but still it doesn't work . The field Start Date in my code , has the value 24 of October instead of 25

Comment: Actually, it's wired issue, could you please check the server date time setting if you are working on SharePoint On-prem?!

Comment: @M.Qassas Actually it is SharePoint Online BUT my development environment is hosted on Azure VM . So Visual Studio is hosted on Azure VM and not on my pc. However the debugging takes place again on Azure. I have checked property "Kind" of StartDate and is set to UTC. Current Date is displayed correctly to 25 October.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you query in SharePoint it returns the results in UTC . So the solution was to transform the returned date fields to localtime . Here is the solution :

```
DateTime startDateUTC = Convert.ToDateTime(approvedLeaveItem["StartDate"]);

DateTime endDateUTC = Convert.ToDateTime(approvedLeaveItem["EndDate"]);

DateTime startDateLocal = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToString(startDateUTC.ToLocalTime()));

DateTime endDateLocal = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToString(endDateUTC.ToLocalTime()));
```